# C++ understanding ADL

Tags: c++

I wrote this function to Join container of objects into string based on give delimiter.

```
template<typename Container>
std::string Join(Container const& input, char delimiter)
{    
    using std::to_string;

    return std::accumulate(++std::begin(input), std::end(input), to_string(*std::begin(input)) 
            , [&delimiter](std::string const& a, typename Container::const_reference b) { return a + delimiter + to_string(b); });            
}
```

As you can see I've added the `using std::to_string;` for ADL work around when container's type is already a string.

and I've implemented (both `to_string` & `Join` in global namesapce):

```
const std::string& to_string(std::string const& str) {  return str; }
```

Now consider these `Join` invocations:

```
Join(std::vector<std::string>{ "1", "2"}, ','); //Fail to compile
Join(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2}, ','); //Compiles
```

But when I add `using ::to_string;` to `Join`:

```
template<typename Container>
std::string Join(Container const& input, char delimiter)
{    
    using std::to_string;
    using ::to_string;            

    return std::accumulate(++std::begin(input), std::end(input), to_string(*std::begin(input)) 
            , [&delimiter](std::string const& a, typename Container::const_reference b) { return a + delimiter + to_string(b); });            
}
```

Both calls compiles:

```
Join(std::vector<std::string>{ "1", "2"}, ',');
Join(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2}, ',');
```

Can someone explain what's going on there, is there some kind of "hiding" of global `to_string` happens ?

Comment: Returning a reference from a function who's lifetime depends on the lifetime of a function parameter is unsafe and may easily cause undefined behaviour. Concerning your problems, please be a bit more precise. For example, you said you tried different things and they gave errors. You fail to mention what attempts you made exactly (i.e. enough info for anyone to reproduce) and what exactly those errors where. At the moment, your question is off-topic because it doesn't provide enough info by far.

Comment: @ulrich worst part is solved by `string&& to_string(string&&)=delete`, or `string to_string(string&& in) {return std::move(in); }` -- now only modestly dangerous.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I agree with your statement regarding my custom `to_string`, I brought it up just for example. In any case in my example when my `to_string` is invoked by `Join` or `std::accumulate`  object still alive upon return. I've also edited my question, I think it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

When you `using`, the considered overloads are those found via looking in that namespsce, and those found via ADL.

None of thr types are in the root namespace.

To fix this, write

```
namespsce notstd {
  std:string const& my_to_string(std::string const& in){return in;}
  std::string my_to_string(std::string&& in){return std;:move(in);}
  template<class T> std::string my_to_string( T const& in ){
    using std::to_string;
    return to_string(in);
  }
}
```

this does not support sfinae early failure.  That requires adding a `details` namespace and some decltypes.

But other than that, you can replace your using and to_string with `notstd::my_to_string`.

Comment: Why `to_string` from global namesapce in my example does not qualify for look up ? It only works when I explicitly add it. Both `Join` & `to_string` live in global namesapce.

Comment: @JobNick because you said `using std::to_string;`.  Once you have done that, you look in the using namespace, and in the namespace of the arguments (and their template arguments).